# How would I implement a star rating system into my Database design?

Tags: mysql, database, erd, rating-system

I am currently making an Android app where I want to allow users to rate posts, posted by other users.

[image: ERD model of Database]

This is my current design, however, would I include Rating as a separate table or included in the Media upload table?

If it is a separate table would it be something like this?

Rating table: (Rating, PostID, Rating_Count, Average_Rating)

If anything else looks wrong with my design that would also be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to track each individual rate? or just an average per post?

Comment: I'd of thought to get an average rating per a post I would need to record each individual vote on a specified post?

Comment: You should track the ratings on a per post basis. This allows you more flexibility in the long run as well as being in NF

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on how you want the ratings to work, who gets to up-vote or down-vote, whether you track everyone that votes to keep from having multiple votes from the same person, etc.

This is what I would do:  add a unique numeric (long?) `RatingID` field for each vote, link the `PostID` field to the Comments table, add a `Rating` (integer) field that is limited to values from 0 to 5 (or whatever range you prefer), and then calculate the average from all votes cast (delete the `Rating_Count` and `Average_Rating` fields).  You could define a **view** to calculate the average ratings for each post to use for your routine for determining how to display it next to the Post.

Also, I would use an ID for each user, not use their names.

So my table would look like this:

`RatingID, PostID, UserID, Rating`

Also, to keep users from voting multiple times, the table would not allow multiple entries for the same `PostID` and `UserID`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to store the Rating.

If you want to track each individual rating. You will need a Rating table with the following:

```
Column
---------
RatingID (PK)
Username (FK) (UserDetailsID if you change the primary key of the UserDetails table)
PostID (FK)    
RatingScore
DateRated
```

In the app, you would then pull back every `RankScore` with that `PostID` and do the calculation based off a count of said `PostID`.

I would recommend the above method because it will allow you do more things with the Ratings in the future. Plus, you have a good structure to follow in place with your `Comments` table. ex. Show who Rated what and at what score.

If you want to attach it to the `Post` table, another table is not needed. You would simply add `Rating_Count` and `Average_Rating` to the table. In your app, you would than have to perform an update every time the Post is rated. You would have to pull the `Rating_Count` and `Average_Rating`, increment the `Rating_Count` by one, recalculate the `Average_Rating` and perform the update.

My second suggestion is less flexible if you ever want to enhance your Rating setup though.

Comment: On a side note, your `UserDetails` table should have a primary key of `UserDetailsID` and not `Username` to be a normalized database. See: http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/sql-design-how-choose-primary-key

Comment: SO just to double check...The RatingScore would be the field which has values 1-5 stars? and then on the app, it will display the overall average of all the rating scores of a specific PostID, I presume is based on a separate SQL function?

Comment: @ChristianBryant Yes, `RatingScore` would have the value the specific User rated the Post. Then, you could either create a Stored Proc(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) to retrieve the average or do the logic inside your Android App code.

Comment: Thankyou very much, been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you can use stretcher like this

```
enter code here
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->ipAddress('ip')->nullable();
        $table->integer('star');
        $table->string('type');           
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('average')->nullable()->default(0);
        $table->integer('count_star')->default(0)->nullable();
        $table->float('star_avg')->default(0)->nullable();
        $table->float('unstar_avg')->default(0)->nullable();
```